# Number of homomorphism between $(\mathbb{Q}^{+}, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In interview of NISER , it was asked:

Prove that there are finitely many homomorphism between $(\mathbb{Q}^{+}, \cdot)$  and $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$.

I know that number of homomorphism between $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$  and $(\mathbb{Q}^{+}, \cdot)$ is $1$ as there is only one element namely $0$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ of finite order. But in my question given above, domain has one element of finite order whereas condomain  have all element of finite order.  This is difficult for me to handle this because I cannot use the relation $o(f(a))$ divides $o(a)$ for all finite order element in Domain where $f$ is a group homomorphism.

Thanks

Comment: What’s $Q^+$? I assume $ℚ_{> 0} = \{q ∈ ℚ;~q > 0\}$?

Comment: what are the possible finite order elements in $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$?

Comment: Yes,,  you are correct @k.stm

Comment: I have tried revrse part which is one

Answer (score 0):

Every positive rational can be written as $n/m$ for some positive integers $n,m$. Therefore it can also be written as $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$ with $p_i$ prime and $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ due the fundamental theorem of arithmetic applied to both numerator and denominator. You can check that the association $n/m\mapsto p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$ defines a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}^+\to\bigoplus_{p\text{ primes}}\mathbb{Z}$ with the free abelian group of infinite countable rank on the right side.

So this shows that there are infinitely many homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}^+$ to any non-trivial group $G$.

On the other hand if $G$ is finite (or more generally periodic) then there can't be a non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Q}^+$. Simply because $\mathbb{Q}^+$ has no nonzero elements of finite order.

Comment: How do you deduce that there are inifinitely many homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ to any nontrivial group G from your above argument?

Comment: @Siraj If $F$ is a free abelian group with a set of free generators $A\subseteq F$ then any function $A\to G$ extends to a unique group homomorphism $F\to G$. In this case I've shown that $\mathbb{Q}^+$ is free abelian with countable set of generators. And there are infinitely many functions from a countable set to a set with at least 2 elements.